# \mathlarger does not make anything larger

Tags: math-mode, size

I am using VerbTeX on an iPhone. The `\mathlarger` command in math mode does not actually make anything larger. Text and and symbols within it do not get sized differently. Why?

Commands like `\big` and `\LARGE` also have no effect and `\scalebox` throws an error if I use a command like `\|` inside the second set of braces following it.

Remember, this is all in math mode (e.g., `$...$`).

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\underset{i=0} {\overset{\lfloor l/n \rfloor} {\mathlarger{\|}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: does your code build with larger sizes on a different TeX distribution? What if you run your tex code on a desktop, or on overleaf? (First you should figure out if the issue is with your code or with VerbTeX specifically.)

Comment: hard to guess your issue as you show no code but scalebox like mbox requires to (re)enter math so `\scalebox{2}{$ some \| math here$}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was using `\scalebox` in math mode.

Comment: you still need `$` inside the box.

Comment: @WillieWong Code was added.

Comment: @Melab Are you looking for something like `\bigg|`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz your suggestions are so small compared to mine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I'm not such a \Bigg TeX wizard :)

Comment: `\mathlarger` doesn't do what you think it does (see the `relsize` documentation).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `\overset`, `\underset` and `\mathlarger` for this application.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vertop}{\DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\Vertop@\relax}\slimits@}
\newcommand{\Vertop@}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\expandafter\big\fi\|\vphantom{\sum}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Vertop_{i=0}^{\lfloor l/n \rfloor} \quad \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor l/n \rfloor}$

\[
\Vertop_{i=0}^{\lfloor l/n \rfloor} \quad \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor l/n \rfloor}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\big`  (or here `\Bigg`) does make the || larger:

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\underset{i=0} {\overset{\lfloor l/n \rfloor} {\|}}$

$\underset{i=0} {\overset{\lfloor l/n \rfloor} {\Bigg\|}}$
\end{document}
```